# Send a json object as a parameter in the Http get request dart flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

My url is such`http://www.org.com`. I wish to send it a json object as a query parameter `address = {"address_id" : "A123456" }`.

How do I do so in the following method :

```
final http.Response result = await
 http.Client().get(
     url, headers: {“abc”: abc} 
);
```

So my request url should look like this url = http://www.org.com?address={"address_id": "A123456"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either glue the parts together yourself, like this:

```
  var j = json.encode({'address_id': 'A123456'});
  var url = Uri.encodeFull('http://www.org.com/?address=$j');
  http.get(url);
```

Or you could use the Uri constructor, like this:

```
  var url = Uri(scheme: 'http', host: 'www.org.com', query: 'address=$j');
```